# How to set the weight in the Relative Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating a box that will show some data in that.I want to set the positions of the textview so that if the text size increase it can be handled easliy.

I have created this layout but the issue is if the text size i am getting larger from the server then it is getting messed up with each other how could we handle this.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@layout/rectangle_shape" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/approvalId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="ApprovalId :"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/approvalId_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/approvalId"
            android:text="Co07039645" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/admin_remarks"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/approvalId"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="AdminRemarks :"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/admin_remarks_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/admin_remarks"
            android:layout_below="@+id/approvalId_value"
            android:text="Test Remarks Done by Pooja who is the admin of the employee" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/current_status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/admin_remarks"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Current Status :"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/current_status_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/current_status"
            android:layout_below="@+id/admin_remarks_value"
            android:text="Approved" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/update_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/current_status"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Update Time :"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/update_time_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/update_time"
            android:layout_below="@+id/current_status_value"
            android:text="2014-03-07 13:42:18" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/previous_costcenter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/update_time"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Previous Costcenter :"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/previous_costcenter_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/previous_costcenter"
            android:layout_below="@+id/update_time_value"
            android:text="All" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/current_costcenter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/previous_costcenter"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Previous Costcenter :"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/current_costcenter_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/current_costcenter"
            android:layout_below="@+id/previous_costcenter_value"
            android:text="All" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Remarks will have the maximum length of data rest will similar as i have posted in the XML

Comment: also what is the use of outer relative layout single relative layout is enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here according to your question you can't use Weight for Relativelayout. If you want to use then you can use Linear Layout with horizontal or vertical orientation. So answer from your question,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/result"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/approvalId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="ApprovalId :"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/approvalId_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Co07039645" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/admin_remarks"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:text="Admin Remarks :"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/admin_remarks_value"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Test Remarks Done by Pooja who is the admin of the employee" />
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/current_status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Current Status :"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/current_status_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Approved" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/update_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Update Time :"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/update_time_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="2014-03-07 13:42:18" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/previous_costcenter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Previous Costcenter :"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/previous_costcenter_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="All" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/current_costcenter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Previous Costcenter :"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/current_costcenter_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="All" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can not. `weight` is defined for `LinearLayout` only. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#weight) the documentation.

Comment: ... and its derivates (RadioGroup, TableRow , ...).

Comment: so how can we handle this is Relative layout

Comment: changing those in LinearLayout

Answer (score 0):

You can't set `weight` in `RelativeLayout`. If you want to maintain your layout with `weight` then you should use `Linearlayout.